# discord.py Как посчитать количество ботов на сервере?

Tags: python, discord.py

Хочу сделать, чтобы бот мог считать статистику сервера. Не знаю как посчитать количество ботов.
Пробовал перебором всех участников, но если много участников подсчеты затягивается.
Есть ли какой-либо оптимальный способ сделать это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async def bots_count(ctx: commands.Context):
    return await ctx.send(f"Кол-во ботов на сервере: {len(([member for member in ctx.guild.members if member.bot]))}")
```